# file upload without <input type="file"> element in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, remove.bg

I'm trying to automate the process to upload the pictures on [remove.bg](https://remove.bg/upload) but I'm unable to find the input field for the file in inspect elements. I know that by using input and `send_keys` we can automate this but what should I do in this case when the input field is not visible. This is what I've tried till now.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
test = driver.get("https://www.remove.bg/upload")

input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
print (input)
```

Comment: Why not to use their API when they have it?

Comment: @Leemosh I'm doing this as a fun project to learn selenium. I know I can use API but I don't prefer it for this project.

Comment: And what should be the expected behaviour? From what I see you just need to find the right XPath to the button and then continue. Or do you expect something else?

Comment: You may see the <input type='file'> element appear (being injected via javascript) after interacting with the DOM... (ex: after clicking a "browse" button, or after drag/dropping.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following xpath to click the upload button because there is no input tag in that website.

```
//button[contains(text(),'Upload Image')]
```